# multiprocessing in Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, multiprocessing

I have dictionary of dictionaries I am iterating through. Currently I run this in serial, processing 1 item in the list at a time and this works fine, but I would like to speed up the processing of these by using the multiprocessing library.

There is a lot of info available regarding Process/Threads/Pools but am unsure how I would go about implementing this.

I'd like to have the option to specify for example max of 5 threads/processes at a time but am unsure how the iteration works (i.e. do I iterate through the 'tasks' first or do I iterate through the number of threads/processes?

e.g. I have a single dictionary containing 2 levels of hierarchy:

```
dict = {'router1': {'id': 1, 'name': 'rtr1_core'}, 'router2': {'id': 2, 'name': 'rt2_core'}, 'router3': {'id': 3, 'name': 'rtr3_access'}}
```

(Note, I've simplified the list of items in each of the routers - realistically there are 20+ keys in each dict, but I'm using id and name to keep it simple.)

So I iterate through router1... router 3 and each '{'id': 1, 'name': 'rtr1_core'}' dictionary needs to be passed to the 'process_routers' function containing a single argument (the dict).

I don't need to share info between processes.

I've managed to get:

```
    # Process the data
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=process_rtr, args=(rtr_data,))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Which seems to run it in serial still - how do I run these in parallel in up to x threads?

In reality I'm looking to execute the process_rtr function about 50k times in about 5-10 threads based on our current hardware. So it would be great to specify number of threads/processes so I can adjust this as needed.

Many Thanks for your time and help in advance.

Frank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using Python 3.6, have you considered the asyncio library? I'm not sure what you're doing in your process_rtr function, so you may need to look at some of the asyncio compatible libraries ([async libraries](https://github.com/timofurrer/awesome-asyncio)). Should be able to do something like this:

```
import asyncio
import random
dict = {'router1': {'id': 1, 'name': 'rtr1_core'},
        'router2': {'id': 2, 'name': 'rt2_core'},
        'router3': {'id': 3, 'name': 'rtr3_access'}}

async def process_rtr(id, name):
    """Do your execution here."""
    s_time = await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(0, 5))
    print(f"Processing {id}, {name}")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(process_rtr(**router_details))
                               for router, router_details
                               in dict.items()]
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
loop.close()
```

Comment: I've added code to display the PID and timestamp and seems this is still using the same PID and doing it in serial. What I'm trying to do is process all 3 routers in parallel.

Comment: Check out the updates above; I threw an await before the sleep so you could see that they're executing in parallel. This will now wait until the sleep function is complete to print.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a look tomorrow - Need to spend tonight catching up on the basics and reading some more. I think I need to break it all down and understand what is going on before moving on! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your framework is a bit off. Make sure you set up N jobs.

```
jobs = [Process(target=yourfunction, args=(yourdata) for i in range(numberofthreads)]

for j in jobs:
    j.start()
for j in jobs:
    j.join()
```

But note that if you say the following you will might be disappointed:

```
manager = Manager()
yourdata= manager.dict(routerdict)
```

The managed dictionary will pickle up all of your data and make it safe for locking. That takes time. Things go a lot faster if you just have a managed list with IDs or whatever. If `yourfunction` can get access to the underlying data by pulling it out of some other source you can gain a lot of speed. All you need is a managed/locked list of simple elements (routerid1, routerid2, ...) instead of a giant shared wad of data (data that was so massive that you wanted to parallelize the processing of it...)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So if I have a dict of items where would the 'for keys in dict' statement go? I'm struggling to work out how I would add a job into the 'jobs' list. In my example I would like to add the 3 routers (jobs) into the job list and if I had the option to say 2 threads I'd expect it to run router1 and router2 together, then run router3. I'm justing using 2 threads as an example - I would need to tweak the threads to get the optimal use of the CPUs. Thanks.

Comment: `yourfunction` has as its core loop: `while listofrouterids: thisrouterid = listofrouterids.pop()`. Then there are embedded functions inside that loop: `d = acquiredata(thisrouterid)` & `result = processdata(d)`